# Get a status code using pytest and mock in django

Tags: django, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to get a status code for a test using mock.

I'm doing something like this:

```py
def test_example(mocker):
    MyTest = mocker.patch("my_app_example.my_file_example.requests.post")
    test_ob_mock = Mock()
    test_ob_mock.status_code = 200
    MyTest.return_value = test_ob_mock
    ...
```

This way I get what I want (post returns a status code), but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.